# WPF & MVVM Light - Closing a child window with buttons via Messenger

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

In my project I have a child window, multiple instances of which can be open at a time. They take in an instance of an object, display information about it, and return information about it. Right now it's working but I have to close the window with the 'X' in the top corner. I would like to be able to close the windows with 'Accept' and 'Cancel' buttons. Should I click accept, I would like to have MVVM Light's messenger send back the appropriate data (which is already functional) and close the window. If I click 'cancel' the changes should be discarded and the window closed. Unfortunately I don't know of a good (and MVVM-friendly) way to close the windows using buttons. I have looked into using commands to no avail and I'm not sure how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated. I don't really know what code to post in this situation...

```
<Button x:Name="btnAccept"
          Grid.Row="2"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Content="Accept"
          Command="{Binding AcceptCommand}"/>
<Button x:Name="btnCancel"
          Grid.Row="2"
          Grid.Column="2"
          Content="Cancel" />
```

---

```
    private void ExecuteAcceptCommand()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(Adv.Name); 

        //Close the window here somehow?
    }
```

Comment: Introducing the MVVM abstraction allows you to test the view state and behavior. This really isn't something you would test and as such is best handled in code behind.

Comment: I wouldn't be opposed at all to using code-behind in this situation. If you'd be willing to propose an answer that would get this to work I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: Actually, the message the Messenger sends relies on data from the ViewModel, so I can't close the window completely from code-behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class WindowClass
{
    public WindowClass()
    {
       var messenger = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IMessenger>();
       messenger.Register<CloseWindowMessage>(this, _ => Close());
    }
}
```

Where `CloseWindowMessage` is

```
public class CloseWindowMessage : MessageBase {}
```

Comment: What framework is this designed for? `ServiceLocator` does not have a .Get property for me.

Comment: That was out of my head. Many implementations are different. Since you are probably using Simple Ioc with MVVM Light I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. For `CloseWindowMessage`, I assume I need to make a class for that. Is there anything in particular that I need to include?

Comment: You can pass data with the Message class that you create but I tend not to pass data with my messages out of personal choice. I prefer to get my data from whatever class is responsible for it.

Comment: VS isn't recognizing `CloseWindowMessage`, that's why I thought I had to use a custom class.

Comment: Right, you'll have to declare/define it.

Comment: I created the class originally and inherited from `MessageBase` but now I get an error saying "No overload for method 'Register' takes 1 argument'.

Comment: I assumed you knew the syntax. I'll check the MVVM Light implementation and update it.

Comment: When I use the code in the answer you proposed, the child window won't open and the program crashes. When I use `Messenger.Default.Register<CloseWindowMessage>(this, _ => Close());`, the command works but it closes all open child windows.

Comment: Also, I've been looking into tokens but haven't managed to get them to work for this scenario.

Comment: I assumed you were putting your messenger instance in the IoC Container which it is not and that is why you are getting the exceptions. You could make a unique message for each window or use tokens or put some logic in the window to see if its visible or any number of other things. The general takeaway here is that you can send a message to make the window close and that technique makes your VM testable (which is the original goal of the MVVM abstraction).

Comment: There are a handful of other ways that don't involve sending messages. You can have your window fetch the VM from your container and add a click handler in the codebehind. The handler then inspects the vm state to see if that particular window should close. Again, this is a general technique and specifics are up to you.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help; I certainly do appreciate it. Everything seems to be in working order now.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple child windows register for same type of message,

You need to make sure that this message is only received by correct child window or all child windows will receive same message, but only the right one will close.
In this case, the message needs to contain a property that has correct value to let child window to determine if it is the one to close.

MVVMLight has facility called "token" when you register or send message.

Check this out:

[How to send message to one view of many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133083/how-to-send-message-to-one-view-of-many)